# Relational Algebra using winrdbi - count

Tags: count, aggregate-functions, relational-algebra

i am studying relational algebra and i am using winrdbi to check if my queries are correct

i am trying to get the count from a colum like this:

q1:=count(tr_numb)(tree)

however i keep getting an error 'query_alg.:Check input format

any idea what i am doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, WinRDBI does not support aggregate functions with Relational Algebra.